# Mysql duplication error

Tags: mysql

I've wrote a query like below in order to insert unique 'project_title' value in the table ('projects').

```
INSERT INTO projects (projects.project_title, projects.description) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'a title', 'a description') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT projects.project_title FROM projects WHERE projects.project_title = 'a title') LIMIT 1
```

This works fine until a same entry for both project title and project description entered and the query will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO projects (projects.project_title, projects.description) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'text', 'text') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT projects.project_title FROM projects WHERE projects.project_title = 'text') LIMIT 1
```

Now, I get this error:

```
[Err] 1060 - Duplicate column name 'text'
```

How to get rid of this duplication error?!

Comment: try giving alias to the columns `...SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'text' AS firstText, 'text' AS secondText) AS tmp ....`

Comment: Thanks, It solved!

Comment: @1000111 make it an answer! \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the **erroneous** statement here:

```
SELECT 
 tmp.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'text', 'text'
) AS tmp;
```

This query will generate this error

> [Err] 1060 - Duplicate column name 'text'

Because you didn't give any alias to columns.

**Solution:**

Give alias to the columns:

```
SELECT 
  tmp.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
      'text' AS firstText, 
      'text' AS secondText
) AS tmp;
```